# Flattening array from 2d to 1d

Tags: c#

Let's say we have 2 arrays:

```
double[,] a = new double[width,height];
double[] b = new double[width*height];
```

We fill a with some numbers, let's say 0s and 1s.

Why does:

```
for(int i = 0; i < a.GetLength(0); i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < a.GetLength(1); j++)
        b[i * a.GetLength(0) + j] = a[i,j];
```

return only 0s in all fields of b[]?

Comment: Uh, int Array.GetLenght(int dimension) Gets a 32-bit integer that represents the number of elements in the specified dimension of the  System.Array, i thought it's standard in VS2013. Also yes i run debugger, it correctly loops over the a array, showing correct values on watch, but for some reason it doesn't pass them to b array.

Comment: So you didn't notice your own typo `Array.GetLenght` that's why I asked if that was a Custom Method of your own.. it should be `Array.GetLength`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to multiply by the length of the second dimension, not the first:

```
b[i * a.GetLength(1) + j] = a[i,j];
```

Beyond that, there are less efficient but harder to mess up ways of doing this:

```
b = a.Cast<double>.ToArray();
```

Comment: In my case, the a array is 16x16 so shouldn't really matter by which one I'm multiplying

Comment: Just to make sure, are you (1) sure that `a` is not all 0's and (2) sure this code is running and matches the code in the question?

Comment: @ChrisPitman you should not have answered the question in the first place, if you're not sure what the OP is actually doing in his code. -1

Comment: Chris, I have a richtexxtbox displaying my a array, so i can see it's not all 0. Then I display b array and it's all 0.

Comment: @Mihai I understand perfectly well what the question is asking. I'm just not sure the poster asked what they needed to ask. Januszoff: Can you create a short and complete program showing your problem and edit the question? I think there's something going on outside of this excerpt that is causing your issue.

Comment: @Chris I found the error, it was my mistake (poor eyesight) in one place I confused i with j. Sorry for the commotion.

Comment: @Januszoff Haha, that was the first thing I checked for. I've done that so many times.

Comment: Another fail-safe and quite efficient (I did not measure) way: `int idx = 0; foreach (var entry in a) { b[idx] = entry; idx++; }` Of course you can put the incrementing inside the preceding expression statement, to have only one statement in the loop, but that *can* be messed up.

Answer (score 2):

By the way. A much more efficient way to convert your 2-d array to 1-d array is:

```
public static T[] ToPlainArray<T>(this T[,] array)
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    int sizeInBytes = Marshal.SizeOf(type);
    T[] buffer = new T[array.Length];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(array, 0, buffer, 0, array.Length * sizeInBytes);
    return buffer;
}
```

Usage:

```
double[] b = a.ToPlainArray();
```

Or

```
double[] b = ToPlainArray(a);
```

Comment: Since .NET 4.5.1 (from 2013, included in Visual Studio 2013) you can use [`Marshal.SizeOf<T>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn261466.aspx) directly which is more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line:

```
Debug.WriteLine("b[" + (i* a.GetLenth(1) + j) + "] = " + b[i * a.GetLength(1) + j]);
```

and check what happens